# Invalid Redirect error when trying to create user in Chef Server 12

Tags: chef, knife

When I try to create a user in Chef Enterprise Server, I am getting an error

> sudo chef-server-ctl user-create admin m n ******@i&&&.com chefrocks --filename admin.pem
>
> ERROR: Invalid Redirect: POST request was redirected from https://127.0.0.1/users/ to http://127.0.0.1/en-US/users. Only GET and HEAD support redirects.
>       Change your server location in knife.rb to the server's FQDN to avoid unwanted redirections.

`knife.rb` is pointing to my server FQDN only.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you sure that there is no other `knife.rb` in place? Have you checked the very top [here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html). You could try `--config` to manually specify the path to the `knife.rb`. And.. how does your `knife.rb` look like? Maybe there is a typo so that the URL is not recognized?

Comment: Do you have your `hostname` set correctly for the server as well?

Comment: I used --config to set the location of knife.rb.Still i get error but a different one Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to https://127.0.0.1/users/ .I have set the hostname in knife.rb..Do we have to set it in any other place?